# Standalone curve_fit methode

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I have a question regarding scipy's [curve_fit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) method. I have to 
perform curve fitting an some values and this function would greatly help.

But unfortunately the scipy installation does not have this function yet, and
a upgrade of scipy is unlikely to happen anytime soon.

Now I tried somethings, to make it work but sadly I got nowhere.

I also found someone saying that curve_fit can be done [standalone](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scipy-user/rsaiaJpJOqs/rd7kddand7kJ), but without explanation. Could someone tell me if it is possible and if yes how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`curve_fit` is a rather simple wrapper for `leastsq`, that's why it is mentioned in that Google post that you can just copy and paste the `curve_fit` function  to get a stand alone version. The function is located in `..\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minipack.py`.

Under the hood it is not really stand-alone. `leastsq` calls `minipack` under the hood.

include `curve_fit` in you source, and get the namespace ready by `from scipy.optimize import *`, and you should be able to use it as a 'stand alone'. Let me know if you have further question.